# Sencha Touch 2: switch between two panels with a "fade" animation?

Tags: android, performance, animation, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm wondering what is the best way to swap out two panels on the screen with a fade effect?

I have two panels which I have positioned over top of each other using CSS. panelOne is visible, panelTwo is hidden.

On click of another button (not on either panel), I want panelOne to fade out and panelTwo to fade in.

I currently have this working using the code below, but I find it's quite laggy on some Android devices we have here for testing. Is there a better way to do it than what I'm currently using? How can I improve this animation?

This code is executed on button tap:

```
Ext.Anim.run(panelOne, 'fade', {
   duration: 100,
   after: function() {
      panelOne.hide();
   }
});
Ext.Anim.run(panelTwo, 'fade', {
   out: false,
   duration: 100,
   before: function() {
      panelTwo.show();
   }
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to use `Ext.Anim` such long.

For example, your app has an `Ext.Container` which contains `panelOne` and `panelTwo` as the first and second item, respectively.

Then if you want to navigate from `panelOne` to `panelTwo` with a `fade` animation, just simply use:

`Ext.getCmp('your_container_id').animateActiveItem(1,'fade')`

**or** you can do this:

- Add `showAnimation: 'fadeIn'` to your panelTwo's config
- Add `hideAnimation: 'fadeOut'` to your panelOne's config

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

to control other config, such as duration, use:
hideAnimation: {type:'fadeOut', duration: 1000}